# Using os.walk() to recursively traverse directories in Python

Tags: python, os.walk

I want to navigate from the root directory to all other directories within and print the same.

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import fnmatch

for root, dir, files in os.walk("."):
        print root
        print ""
        for items in fnmatch.filter(files, "*"):
                print "..." + items
        print ""
```

And here's my O/P:

```
.

...Python_Notes
...pypy.py
...pypy.py.save
...classdemo.py
....goutputstream-J9ZUXW
...latest.py
...pack.py
...classdemo.pyc
...Python_Notes~
...module-demo.py
...filetype.py

./packagedemo

...classdemo.py
...__init__.pyc
...__init__.py
...classdemo.pyc
```

Above, `.` and `./packagedemo` are directories.

However, I need to print the O/P in the following manner:

```
A
---a.txt
---b.txt
---B
------c.out
```

Above, `A` and `B` are directories and the rest are files.

Comment: I would like to add this little post here,about the power of python:                                                           >>> print 2 * '--'
----

Answer (score 333, accepted):

This will give you the desired result

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

# traverse root directory, and list directories as dirs and files as files
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    path = root.split(os.sep)
    print((len(path) - 1) * '---', os.path.basename(root))
    for file in files:
        print(len(path) * '---', file)
```

Comment: path = os.path.relpath(root, basepath).split(os.sep)

Comment: @Ajay be paranoid and always do `os.walk(u".")` because paths can be Unicode.

Comment: Better still, `os.path.curdir`

Comment: I had been using `os.path.walk` for a while, so `os.walk` is new to me! Cool beans.

Comment: @Semprini what is `basepath` equal to in your code?

Comment: It works, but I cannot understand where the recursion happens here? Could you please clarify that?

Comment: os.walk hides the recursion.  But the default `topdown` makes the recursion available: if you filter `dirs` in-place, then only the ones remained are examined: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk

Answer (score 48):

Recursive walk through a directory where you get ALL files from all dirs in the current directory and you get ALL dirs from the current directory - because codes above don't have a simplicity (imho):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootFolderPath):
    for filename in files:
        doSomethingWithFile(os.path.join(root, filename))
    for dirname in dirs:
        doSomethingWithDir(os.path.join(root, dirname))
```

Comment: Most helpful answer. Note that `os.path.join(root, filename)` gives the full path to the file, even if the file is nested in several directories.

Answer (score 38):

try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""FileTreeMaker.py: ..."""

__author__  = "legendmohe"

import os
import argparse
import time

class FileTreeMaker(object):

    def _recurse(self, parent_path, file_list, prefix, output_buf, level):
        if len(file_list) == 0 \
            or (self.max_level != -1 and self.max_level <= level):
            return
        else:
            file_list.sort(key=lambda f: os.path.isfile(os.path.join(parent_path, f)))
            for idx, sub_path in enumerate(file_list):
                if any(exclude_name in sub_path for exclude_name in self.exn):
                    continue

                full_path = os.path.join(parent_path, sub_path)
                idc = "┣━"
                if idx == len(file_list) - 1:
                    idc = "┗━"

                if os.path.isdir(full_path) and sub_path not in self.exf:
                    output_buf.append("%s%s[%s]" % (prefix, idc, sub_path))
                    if len(file_list) > 1 and idx != len(file_list) - 1:
                        tmp_prefix = prefix + "┃  "
                    else:
                        tmp_prefix = prefix + "    "
                    self._recurse(full_path, os.listdir(full_path), tmp_prefix, output_buf, level + 1)
                elif os.path.isfile(full_path):
                    output_buf.append("%s%s%s" % (prefix, idc, sub_path))

    def make(self, args):
        self.root = args.root
        self.exf = args.exclude_folder
        self.exn = args.exclude_name
        self.max_level = args.max_level

        print("root:%s" % self.root)

        buf = []
        path_parts = self.root.rsplit(os.path.sep, 1)
        buf.append("[%s]" % (path_parts[-1],))
        self._recurse(self.root, os.listdir(self.root), "", buf, 0)

        output_str = "\n".join(buf)
        if len(args.output) != 0:
            with open(args.output, 'w') as of:
                of.write(output_str)
        return output_str

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-r", "--root", help="root of file tree", default=".")
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", help="output file name", default="")
    parser.add_argument("-xf", "--exclude_folder", nargs='*', help="exclude folder", default=[])
    parser.add_argument("-xn", "--exclude_name", nargs='*', help="exclude name", default=[])
    parser.add_argument("-m", "--max_level", help="max level",
                        type=int, default=-1)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(FileTreeMaker().make(args))
```

you will get this:

```
root:.
[.]
┣━[.idea]
┃  ┣━[scopes]
┃  ┃  ┗━scope_settings.xml
┃  ┣━.name
┃  ┣━Demo.iml
┃  ┣━encodings.xml
┃  ┣━misc.xml
┃  ┣━modules.xml
┃  ┣━vcs.xml
┃  ┗━workspace.xml
┣━[test1]
┃  ┗━test1.txt
┣━[test2]
┃  ┣━[test2-2]
┃  ┃  ┗━[test2-3]
┃  ┃      ┣━test2
┃  ┃      ┗━test2-3-1
┃  ┗━test2
┣━folder_tree_maker.py
┗━tree.py
```

Comment: Hi there,  I really love your script, but its a bit too complicated for the project I am working on, is there any chance I could have it as one small function, with only the -r argument present?

Comment: how to print it in a .txt? 
I tried `print(FileTreeMaker().make(args),file=tree)` but it gives me `'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 17-21: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: what is idc stand for

Comment: I wrote something similar with `os.listdir()` too. Yours is much better; I couldn't get the recursion right, it only worked 2 or 3 layers deep. In the end I decided to try again from scratch with `os.walk()` instead, which I thought would be far more suitable. I'm surprised you didn't use it at all here.

Answer (score 15):

There are more suitable functions for this in `os` package. But if you have to use `os.walk`, here is what I come up with

```
def walkdir(dirname):
    for cur, _dirs, files in os.walk(dirname):
        pref = ''
        head, tail = os.path.split(cur)
        while head:
            pref += '---'
            head, _tail = os.path.split(head)
        print(pref+tail)
        for f in files:
            print(pref+'---'+f)
```

output:

```
>>> walkdir('.')
.
---file3
---file2
---my.py
---file1
---A
------file2
------file1
---B
------file3
------file2
------file4
------file1
---__pycache__
------my.cpython-33.pyc
```

Comment: So what are more suitable functions? (in 3.5 if that matters)

Comment: Sorry, no chance to remember what I meant by that. It's possible that I meant `os.listdir` but @ajay's solution beats that.

Answer (score 11):

You could also recursively walk through a folder and lists all it's contents using [pathlib.Path()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

```py
from pathlib import Path


def check_out_path(target_path, level=0):
    """"
    This function recursively prints all contents of a pathlib.Path object
    """
    def print_indented(folder, level):
        print('\t' * level + folder)

    print_indented(target_path.name, level)
    for file in target_path.iterdir():
        if file.is_dir():
            check_out_path(file, level+1)
        else:
            print_indented(file.name, level+1)


my_path = Path(r'C:\example folder')
check_out_path(my_path)
```

Output:

```
example folder
    folder
        textfile3.txt
    textfile1.txt
    textfile2.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

This does it for folder names:

```
def printFolderName(init_indent, rootFolder):
    fname = rootFolder.split(os.sep)[-1]
    root_levels = rootFolder.count(os.sep)
    # os.walk treats dirs breadth-first, but files depth-first (go figure)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootFolder):
        # print the directories below the root
        levels = root.count(os.sep) - root_levels
        indent = ' '*(levels*2)
        print init_indent + indent + root.split(os.sep)[-1]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `os.walk`, and that is probably the easiest solution, but here is another idea to explore:

```
import sys, os

FILES = False

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) > 2 and sys.argv[2].upper() == '/F':
        global FILES; FILES = True
    try:
        tree(sys.argv[1])
    except:
        print('Usage: {} <directory>'.format(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])))

def tree(path):
    path = os.path.abspath(path)
    dirs, files = listdir(path)[:2]
    print(path)
    walk(path, dirs, files)
    if not dirs:
        print('No subfolders exist')

def walk(root, dirs, files, prefix=''):
    if FILES and files:
        file_prefix = prefix + ('|' if dirs else ' ') + '   '
        for name in files:
            print(file_prefix + name)
        print(file_prefix)
    dir_prefix, walk_prefix = prefix + '+---', prefix + '|   '
    for pos, neg, name in enumerate2(dirs):
        if neg == -1:
            dir_prefix, walk_prefix = prefix + '\\---', prefix + '    '
        print(dir_prefix + name)
        path = os.path.join(root, name)
        try:
            dirs, files = listdir(path)[:2]
        except:
            pass
        else:
            walk(path, dirs, files, walk_prefix)

def listdir(path):
    dirs, files, links = [], [], []
    for name in os.listdir(path):
        path_name = os.path.join(path, name)
        if os.path.isdir(path_name):
            dirs.append(name)
        elif os.path.isfile(path_name):
            files.append(name)
        elif os.path.islink(path_name):
            links.append(name)
    return dirs, files, links

def enumerate2(sequence):
    length = len(sequence)
    for count, value in enumerate(sequence):
        yield count, count - length, value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

You might recognize the following documentation from the TREE command in the Windows terminal:

```
Graphically displays the folder structure of a drive or path.

TREE [drive:][path] [/F] [/A]

   /F   Display the names of the files in each folder.
   /A   Use ASCII instead of extended characters.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os 

def tracing(a):
    global i>
    for item in os.listdir(a):
        if os.path.isfile(item):
            print i + item 
        else:
            print i + item 
            i+=i
            tracing(item)

i = "---"
tracing(".")
```

Answer (score 3):

Would be the best way

```
import os

def traverse_dir_recur(directory):
    l = os.listdir(directory)
    for d in l:
        if os.path.isdir(directory + d):
            traverse_dir_recur(directory +  d +"/")
        else:
            print(directory + d)
```

Comment: Not working for me in Python3. I assume the error is in `dir + d`, which might concat them without directory separator. It's probably better to use `os.path.join` for concating directories with file names

Comment: Your slashes are not right in this answer. They are missing from two lines and at then end in the recursive call.

Answer (score 2):

Given a folder name, walk through its entire hierarchy recursively.

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python3
# findLargeFiles.py - given a folder name, walk through its entire hierarchy
#                   - print folders and files within each folder

import os

def recursive_walk(folder):
    for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(folder):
        if subfolders:
            for subfolder in subfolders:
                recursive_walk(subfolder)
        print('\nFolder: ' + folderName + '\n')
        for filename in filenames:
            print(filename + '\n')

recursive_walk('/name/of/folder')
```

Comment: No need to call os.walk recursively, as it already flattens the recursion. That's why it returns the folderName argument.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import os
root_name = next(os.walk("."))[0]
dir_names = next(os.walk("."))[1]
file_names = next(os.walk("."))[2]
```

Here I'm assuming your path as "." in which the root_file and other directories are there.
So, Basically we are just iterating throughout the tree by using next() call, as our os.walk is only generative function.
By doing this we can save all the Directory and file names in dir_names and file_names respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have an arbitrary parent directory with subdirectories as such:

```bash
/home/parent_dir
├── 0_N
├── 1_M
├── 2_P
├── 3_R
└── 4_T
```

And here is what you can do to estimate the *approximate* percent distribution #files in each subdirectory relative to the total #files in parent:

```py
from os import listdir as osl
from os import walk as osw
from os.path import join as osj

def subdir_summary(parent_dir):
    parent_dir_len = sum([len(files) for _, _, files in osw(parent_dir)])
    print(f"Total files in parent: {parent_dir_len}")
    for subdir in sorted(osl(parent_dir)):
        subdir_files_len = len(osl(osj(parent_dir, subdir)))
        print(subdir, subdir_files_len, f"{int(100*(subdir_files_len / parent_dir_len))}%")

subdir_summary("/home/parent_dir")
```

It will print in terminal as follows:

```bash
Total files in parent: 5876
0_N 3254 55%
1_M 509 8%
2_P 1187 20%
3_R 594 10%
4_T 332 5%
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do try this; easy one**

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 import os
 # Creating an empty list that will contain the already traversed paths
 donePaths = []
 def direct(path):
       for paths,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
             if paths not in donePaths:
                    count = paths.count('/')
                    if files:
                          for ele1 in files:
                                print '---------' * (count), ele1
                    if dirs:
                          for ele2 in dirs:
                                print '---------' * (count), ele2
                                absPath = os.path.join(paths,ele2)
              # recursively calling the direct function on each directory
                                direct(absPath)
                   # adding the paths to the list that got traversed 
                                donePaths.append(absPath)

 path = raw_input("Enter any path to get the following Dir Tree ...\n")
 direct(path)
```

========OUTPUT below========

```
 /home/test
 ------------------ b.txt
 ------------------ a.txt
 ------------------ a
 --------------------------- a1.txt
 ------------------ b
 --------------------------- b1.txt
 --------------------------- b2.txt
 --------------------------- cde
 ------------------------------------ cde.txt
 ------------------------------------ cdeDir
 --------------------------------------------- cdeDir.txt
 ------------------ c
 --------------------------- c.txt
 --------------------------- c1
 ------------------------------------ c1.txt
 ------------------------------------ c2.txt
```

Comment: What is the point of the check for already traversed paths? If it's to detect loops caused by links, os.walk apparently defaults to not following links. Is there some other situation?

Answer (score -3):

```
import os

os.chdir('/your/working/path/')
dir = os.getcwd()
list = sorted(os.listdir(dir))
marks = ""

for s_list in list:
    print marks + s_list
    marks += "---"
    tree_list = sorted(os.listdir(dir + "/" + s_list))
    for i in tree_list:
        print marks + i
```

Comment: This does not look like it traverses the whole tree.