# Accessing to subdirectories

Tags: python

I have a function which simply encrypts files inside a directory

```
def encrypt_directory(location):
    os.chdir(location)
    for file in glob.glob("*.*"):
        encrypt_file(file)
        print(file + " is encrypted")
```

My question is: How can i access to subdirectories of `location` and apply `encrypt_file` function to files inside them?

Comment: `os.walk()` is what you need

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using os.walk() to recursively traverse directories in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953842/using-os-walk-to-recursively-traverse-directories-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

```
def encrypt_directory(location):
    for root, _, files in os.walk(location):
        for fil in files:
            fname = os.path.join(root, fil)
            encrypt_file(fname)
            print(fname + " is encrypted")
```