# Python - list all directories/files and follow

Tags: python

I have the following command I'm running on my remote server

`python -c 'import os, json; print json.dumps(os.listdir("."))'`

This works fine for listing files/directories in the current directory however how would I change this to follow directories and list the containing files?

Comment: It seems you need somethink like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16974952/2707359

Comment: @Ilya was thinking same thing, though with some serious nesting to iterate over os.walk and then iterate through os.walks filenames to try and make it a one liner.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a one liner, I can save into a .py file and execute if required.

Answer (score 3):

Python, ever eager to please, provides a standard library function for that. [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.walk) wraps up the pattern of recursively listing files in subdirectories.

Here's how you could json-ify a list of all the files in this directory or any subdirectories. I'm using a two-level [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-comprehension) to concatenate the lists of files:

```
import json
import os

print(json.dumps([file for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.') for file in files]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
out_list = []
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk("."):
    for f in files:
        out_list.append(os.path.join(path, f))
    for d in dirs:
        out_list.append(os.path.join(path, d))

print json.dumps(out_list)
```

This will include directories and files in the output with full path.