# How to make python spot a folder and print its files

Tags: python-3.x

I want to be able to make python print everything in my C drive. I have figured out this to print whats on the first "layer" of the drive,

```
def filespotter():
import os
path = 'C:/'
dirs = os.listdir( path )
for file in dirs:
    print(file)
```

but I want it to go into the other folders and print what is in every other folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list all files of a directory in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python)

Comment: @SencerH. The quesion you shared asks how to list the contents of a directory only, not its subdirectories as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953842/using-os-walk-to-recursively-traverse-directories-in-python

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer** `os.walk` is just fine, I'm here to provide a easier solution.

If you're using python 3.5 or above, you can use [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) with `'**'` and `recursive=True`

For example: `glob.glob(r'C:\**', recursive=True)`

Please note that getting the entire file list of C:\ drive can take a lot of time.

If you don't need the entire list at the same time, [`glob.iglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) is a reasonable choice. The usage is the same, except that you get an iterator instead of a list.

To print everything under C:\

```
for filename in glob.iglob(r'C:\**', recursive=True):
    print(filename)
```

It gives you output as soon as possible.

However if you don't have python 3.5 available, you can see [the source of glob.py](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/glob.py) and adapt it for your use case.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without glob?

Comment: Use `os.walk` if you don't want to use glob. There's plenty of examples in the "possible duplicate" links