# Python: How to replace whitespaces by underscore in the name of ALL files, folders and subfolders?

Tags: python, batch-rename

How can we replace the whitespaces in the names of folders, subfolders and files in a given parent folder?

My initial attempt to replace up to level 8 is given below. I am sure there are better ways. My code looks ugly.
Better solutions are more than welcome.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#


def replace_space_by_underscore(path):
    """Replace whitespace in filenames by underscore."""
    import glob
    import os
    for infile in glob.glob(path):
        new = infile.replace(" ", "_")
        try:
            new = new.replace(",", "_")
        except:
            pass
        try:
            new = new.replace("&", "_and_")
        except:
            pass
        try:
            new = new.replace("-", "_")
        except:
            pass
        if infile != new:
            print(infile, "==> ", new)
        os.rename(infile, new)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        replace_space_by_underscore('*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*')
    except:
        pass
    try:
        replace_space_by_underscore('*/*/*/*/*/*/*')
    except:
        pass
    try:
        replace_space_by_underscore('*/*/*/*/*/*')
    except:
        pass
    try:
        replace_space_by_underscore('*/*/*/*/*')
    except:
        pass
    try:
        replace_space_by_underscore('*/*/*/*')
    except:
        pass
    try:
        replace_space_by_underscore('*/*/*')
    except:
        pass
    try:
        replace_space_by_underscore('*/*')
    except:
        replace_space_by_underscore('*')
```

Comment: What's the goal - the result, or the program itself?

Comment: You can use os.walk() like in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953842/using-os-walk-to-recursively-traverse-directories-in-python

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) that allows you to change the names of the iterated folders on the fly:

```
import os

def replace(parent):
    for path, folders, files in os.walk(parent):
        for f in files:
            os.rename(os.path.join(path, f), os.path.join(path, f.replace(' ', '_')))
        for i in range(len(folders)):
            new_name = folders[i].replace(' ', '_')
            os.rename(os.path.join(path, folders[i]), os.path.join(path, new_name))
            folders[i] = new_name
```

`os.walk` iterates directory tree starting from `parent` in top-down order. For every folder it returns tuple `(current path, list of files, list of folders`). Given folder list can be mutated and `os.walk` will use the mutated contents in the following steps of the iteration.

Folder before run:

```
.
├── new doc
└── sub folder
    ├── another folder
    ├── norename
    └── space here
```

After:

```
.
├── new_doc
└── sub_folder
    ├── another_folder
    ├── norename
    └── space_here
```

Comment: being able to use `os.rename` as a method to rename the file helped me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need a recursive solution. Rename all files in the current directory; then for each subdirectory (if any), descend into that subdirectory X (with `os.chdir(X)`), call the same function again, and ascend back to the parent directory (with `os.chdir("..")`).

Answer (score 1):

Following the exact idea of @niemmi I ended up with this:

**Warning:** Never run this script from HOME directory or from some important directory, it will RENAME all files including HIDDEN files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Date: Dec 15, 2016


def replace_space_by_underscore(parent):
    """Replace whitespace by underscore in all files and folders.

    replaces    , - [ ] () __   ==>  underscore

    """
    import os
    for path, folders, files in os.walk(parent):
        # rename the files
        for f in files:
            old = os.path.join(path, f)
            bad_chars = [r' ', r',', r'-', r'&', r'[', r']', r'(', r')', r'__']
            for bad_char in bad_chars:
                if bad_char in f:
                    new = old.replace(bad_char, '_')
                    print(old, "==>", new)
                    os.rename(old, new)

        # rename the folders
        for i in range(len(folders)):
            new_name = folders[i].replace(' ', '_')
            bad_chars = [r' ', r',', r'-', r'&',
                         r'[', r']', r'(', r')', r'__']
            for bad_char in bad_chars:
                if bad_char in new_name:
                    new_name = new_name.replace(bad_char, '_')
                    print(folders[i], "==> ", new_name)
            old = os.path.join(path, folders[i])
            new = os.path.join(path, new_name)
            os.rename(old, new)
            folders[i] = new_name


if __name__ == "__main__":
    replace_space_by_underscore('.')
```

Comment: Good solution - just needs `old = new` under `os.rename(old, new)` in the files for loop (ie: files with multiple `bad_chars`)