# python - Cannot detect links of other language with os.walk

Tags: python, url-encoding, os.walk

I am trying to get a list of files and directories present in a specified URL. The URL I'm using is of an online Dictionary : [www.shabdkosh.com/kn/browse/](http://www.shabdkish.com/kn/browse). My code is as follows:

```
html_files = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("www.shabdkosh.com/kn/browse"):
    for file in files:
        #Files in shabdkosh have a digit as name to represent page number
        if file.isdigit():
            html_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
```

when I print the contents of files, I get:

```
www.shabdkosh.com/kn/browse/3/1
www.shabdkosh.com/kn/browse/a/1
www.shabdkosh.com/kn/browse/a/10
www.shabdkosh.com/kn/browse/a/2
...
```

This is cool. But other URLs should have also been retrieved. The URLs containing Kannada alphabets are not displayed (Kannada is an Indian Language) even though they exist.

For example,

```
www.shabdkosh.com/kn/browse/ಅ/
```

Like so are not displayed even though they lie in the path "www.shabdkosh.com/kn/browse" specified as the parameter for `os.walk`. So, how do I get `os.walk` to get the list of URLs with the Kannada letters ?

I even tried including the following code at the top of my python file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: ascii -*-
```

But no luck. Any help is appreciated.

**P.S** Sorry if it bothers you that I'm using Old python 2.7.

Comment: Is not that what you wanted `if file.isdigit(file`? remove the condition, you will get more.

Comment: No luck. I even printed the "files" outside the condition. I only get pure English URls

Answer (score 1):

Couple things to try:

1. If you're using any coding at all, it should be utf-8, not ascii. Clearly those are not ascii characters.
2. Make sure your path is unicode, e.g. os.walk(u"www.shabdkosh.com/kn/browse"). See Ciro's comment on [Using os.walk() to recursively traverse directories in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953842/using-os-walk-to-recursively-traverse-directories-in-python)