# How can I can loop entire folder with 3 levels of subfolder in python

Tags: python, pandas

```
Folder         2018
Sub-folder1         01
Sub-folder2            01
Sub-folder3               1234
                          4567
file                          abd.jason
file                          fghg.jason
```

I need to use regex in these files How can I loop the entire folder
`Sub-folder1` is the month 
`Sub-folder2` is the date of each month
`Sub-folder3` is the Submission number(And I need to grasp this number as the name into the data frame

Then I need to use Regex to find something and attache the valued follow SubmissionNumber in DataFrame

How can I loop 3 level of subfolder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using os.walk() to recursively traverse directories in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953842/using-os-walk-to-recursively-traverse-directories-in-python)

Comment: Try pathlib. Path.glob (**/*.jason)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html), see if that answers your question. If you are having trouble with a more specific part of it after that, ask a new question =)

Comment: import os 
rootdir = " "

for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootdir):
    if len(dirName.split("/"[-1])) > 5:
        print(dirName.split("/")[-1])
        for fname in fileList:
            if fname != '.DS_Store':
                print('\t%s' % fname)  This is my code, but I print out some subfolder, but I noly need the subfolder 3

Answer (score 0):

I try another time

```
import os

rootdir = "/Users/yongli/Downloads/Data/JSON Output/Submission/2018"

for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootdir):
    # screen the path splited using '/' and count the length
    if len(dirName.split("/")) > 10: 
        print(dirName.split("/")[-1])
        for fname in fileList:
            if fname != '.DS_Store':
            print('\t%s' % fname)
```