# Python - recursively going through a directory and printing files or empty directory in a text files

Tags: python

I am a python newbie, I have given a task to continuously go in a directory and fetch for a empty sub directory or a files .
if the directory is empty it should write the path to a folder.txt , if the directory has files in it should write a path of that file.
For example:

Dir a contains:

```
a/apple/mango/ess.txt
a/gat.xml
a/apple/asl/cdr/opa/est.py
a/apple/dse/
a/dews
```

Output (folder.txt) file should be :

```
a/apple/dse/
a/dews
```

Output (file.txt) file should be :

```
a/apple/mango/ess.txt
a/gat.xm
a/apple/asl/cdr/opa/est.py
```

I tried using this logic:

```
        for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for files in dirs:
                fp1 = (os.path.join(path, files))
                print (fp1)
                if len(os.listdir(fp1)) == 0:
                    print("Directory is empty")
                    folder_added.write("\n Empty folder found %s \n" % (fp1))
```

but it goes only till two sub folders.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953842/using-os-walk-to-recursively-traverse-directories-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. Each iteration of this loop describes a new directory.
In each directory you want to first check if the list of `files` is empty.
If it is empty, you write the directory path (`root`, in the example below) to file.
If `files` is not empty, you can loop through it and write the filenames to your other output file:

```
f_folders = open('folders.txt', 'w')
f_files = open('files.txt', 'w')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    if not files:
        # Empty directory
        f_folders.write(root + '\n')
    else:
        for f in files:
            fpath = os.path.join(root, f)
            f_files.write(fpath + '\n')
```