# Output directory tree in logical order using os.walk

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk

Not sure if `logical` is the right word here. However, when I run `os.walk` I'm appending paths to a list, and I would like the order to be so that if you were to read top to bottom, it would make sense.

For example, if the path I was looping through was `C:\test` which has a single file, along with folders (each with their own subfolders and files), this is what I'd want the list output to resemble.

```
C:\test
C:\test\test1.txt
C:\test\subfolder1
C:\test\subfolder1\file1.txt
C:\test\subfolder1\file2.txt
C:\test\subfolder2
C:\test\subfolder2\file3.txt
```

However, my output is the following.

```
C:\test\subfolder1
C:\test\subfolder2
C:\test\test1.txt
C:\test\subfolder1\file1.txt
C:\test\subfolder1\file2.txt
C:\test\subfolder2\file3.txt
```

First problem is that `C:\test` doesn't appear.  I could just append `C:\test` to the list. However, I would want `C:\test\test1.txt` to appear directly below it. Ordering ascendingly would just stick it at the end.

When using `os.walk` is there a way for me to append to my list in such as way that everything would be in order?

Code:

```
import os
 
tree = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\test', topdown = True):

    for d in dirs:
       tree.append(os.path.join(root, d))

    for f in files:
        tree.append(os.path.join(root, f))

for x in tree:
    print(x)
```

Edit: By logical order I mean I would like it to appear as top folder, followed by subfolders and files in that folder, files and subfolders in those folders, and so on.

e.g.

```
C:\test
    C:\test\test1.txt
    C:\test\subfolder1
       C:\test\subfolder1\file1.txt
       C:\test\subfolder1\file2.txt
    C:\test\subfolder2
       C:\test\subfolder2\file3.txt
```

Comment: What would "make sense" when reading an inherently 2D data structure in one dimension (top to bottom)? Do you understand that "makes sense" is pretty subjective? Some people might prefer breadth-first, others depth-first. Some might prefer to read alphabetically and ignore the structure entirely. Or directories first then files. Or by date created, or modified... Please explain what *exactly* you want here because right now it's not clear what you mean by "in order".

Comment: The intention of the output snippet was to show what I mean by "in order" and what "makes sense". However, I've updated to add more details on what I mean here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953842/using-os-walk-to-recursively-traverse-directories-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order you want is the order in which `os.walk` iterates over the folders. You just have to append `root` to your list, instead of the folders.

```py
import os
 
tree = []
for root, _, files in os.walk('test'):
    tree.append(root)
    for f in files:
        tree.append(os.path.join(root, f))

for x in tree:
    print(x)
```

### Output

```
test
test/test1.txt
test/subfolder1
test/subfolder1/file1.txt
test/subfolder1/file2.txt
test/subfolder2
test/subfolder2/file3.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should solve your problem

**Explanation:**

1. Loop through your `tree` variable and create a `list` of `tuples` where first element of the `tuple` is the dir/file path and second element is the count of \ in the dir/file path
2. Sort the `list` of `tuples` by the second element of the `tuple`
3. Create a list of the second elements of the `tuples` in your `list`

```
import os
 
tree = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\test', topdown = True):

    for d in dirs:
       tree.append(os.path.join(root, d))

    for f in files:
        tree.append(os.path.join(root, f))

tup = []

def Sort_Tuple(tup):
    """function code sourced from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-sort-a-list-of-tuples-by-second-item/"""
    # getting length of list of tuples
    lst = len(tup)
    for i in range(0, lst):
         
        for j in range(0, lst-i-1):
            if (tup[j][1] > tup[j + 1][1]):
                temp = tup[j]
                tup[j]= tup[j + 1]
                tup[j + 1]= temp
    return tup

for x in tree:
    i = x.count('\\')
    tup.append((x,i))
sorted = Sort_Tuple(tup)

answer = [tup[0] for tup in sorted]

print(answer)
```

This should work. In no way shape or form this is optimized.

Comment: Appreciate the code. Thanks. However, I think the user above has provided all I need, and it's a bit simpler!

Comment: totally agree!!