# How to create a Python nested dictionary based on a FTP tree of folders

Tags: python, dictionary, directory, subdirectory, ftplib

I'm trying to create a dictionary based on a tree of folders located on a FTP server (see image below):

[image]

The result I'm looking for is : A primary dictionnary that have secondary dictionnaries (as keys) with some lists (as values).

```
rootpath = r'C:\Users\_M92\Desktop\myFolder'

dict = {'subfolder1': ['sub-subfolder1', 'sub-subfolder2', 'sub-subfolder3']}, \
       {'subfolder2': ['sub-subfolder1']}, \
       {'subfolder3': ['sub-subfolder1', 'sub-subfolder2']}
```

I have to precise that the sub-subfolders can eventually have some folders within.
Do you have any suggestions how to reach this kind of operations, please ?

#### EDIT :

With @Elmatador DeAngel's suggestion/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73353386/19603419), we get close enough :

```
dict = {'subfolder1': {'sub-subfolder1': 'Empty', 'sub-subfolder2': 'Empty', 'sub-subfolder3': 'Empty'},\
        'subfolder2': {'sub-subfolder1': 'Empty'},  \
        'subfolder3': {'sub-subfolder1': 'Empty', 'sub-subfolder2': 'Empty'}}
```

Comment: Adapt from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953842/using-os-walk-to-recursively-traverse-directories-in-python

Comment: Hi @wkl, Actually, I'm working with directories of an FTP server using [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html). Do you think I can adapt the post you mentionned ? Also, the post doesn't explain how to convert the tree of folders into a dictionary.

Comment: You should specify in your post you're trying to do this with FTP, because FTP does not support normal Path-like operations.

Comment: Have you looked into `os.walk()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am aware that you're looking for a code using FTPlib. I don't have an FTP server to show tje example, but I can be of some help.

You could use the concept of a recursive function; a function that calls itself.

It's simple, scan a folder using `os.listdir()` Then check if it's a folder, and if it is, then recall the same function to do the same operation and add it to a dictionary.

Here's a simple example(without an FTP):

```
import os



dictionary = {}

path = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/SomeFile"

def is_dictionary(path): 

       try:
            os.chdir(path)
            return True
            
       except:
            return False
       
def RecursiveFunc(data, path): 
      
      f = os.listdir(path)
      if f != {}:
       for i in f: 
         if is_dictionary(f"{path}/{i}"):
                if os.listdir(f"{path}/{i}") != []:
                   data[i] = {}
                   RecursiveFunc(data[i], f"{path}/{i}")
                  
                else:
                   data[i] = 'Empty'
     
             
                    
RecursiveFunc(dictionary, path)

print(str(dictionary))
```

You just gotta do the same with the FTPlib library. You can use `FTP.cwd()` to move from a dictionary to another, and `FTP.nlst()` to list all the files in said dictionary, and then call a recursive function to do the same job to the file inside the file.

Output:

```
{'subfolder1': {'sub-subfolder1': 'Empty', 'sub-subfolder2': 'Empty', 'sub-subfolder3': 'Empty'},
{'subfolder2': {'sub-subfolder1': 'Empty'}, 
{'subfolder3': {'sub-subfolder1': 'Empty', 'sub-subfolder2': 'Empty'}}
```

**EDIT**

I wrote a code that almost perfectly resembles the output you desire.

Here it is:

```
import os

dictionary = []

path = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/MyFolder"

def is_dic(path): 

       try:
            os.chdir(path)
            return True
            
       except:
            return False
       
def RecursiveFunc(data, path): 
      
      f = os.listdir(path)
      index = 0
      for i in f:
          
           if is_dic(f"{path}/{i}"):
               if os.listdir(f"{path}/{i}") == []: 
                          data.append(str(i))
                          
                          
               else:
               
                       data.append({i: []})
                       RecursiveFunc(data[index][i], f"{path}/{i}" )
               
               index += 1               
     
             
                          
                          

                      
RecursiveFunc(dictionary, path)


print(str(dictionary))
```

Output:

```
[{'subfolder1': ['sub-subfolder1', 'sub-subfolder2', 'sub-subfolder3']}, 
{'subfolder2': ['sub-subfolder1']}, 
{'subfolder3': ['sub-subfolder1', 'sub-subfolder2']}]
```

Comment: Hi @Elmatador DeAngel, thank you for your help. Please consider the **EDIT** in my post.  
I put the result of your code.

Comment: @L'Artiste No problem. Does that result suffice you or do you need it to be EXACTLY like the one you wrote?

Comment: Unfortunately, I would like to have the one I wrote.

Comment: @L'Artiste I made an edit. You should check it out.

Comment: Thank you so much Elmatador. That's exactly the result I'm looking for.